# write down the transition probability matrix for a certain pattern

Tags: probability, matrices, markov-chains, transition-matrix

Suppose we're generating a sequence of 0s and 1s. We want a specific pattern 0011, and we are given this transition matrix with arbitrary probabilities

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    p & q  \\
    q & p  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

where the first column and row is for 0, and the second column and and row are for 1.

Using this transition matrix, how do we end up with a transition matrix for patter 0011:
(Our states are {1,0,00,001,0011})
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    p&q&0&0&0 \\
    q&0&p&0&0 \\
    0&0&p&q&0 \\
    0&q&0&0&p \\
    0&0&0&0&1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I really have no idea how they arrived to this matrix. I am very lost. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Who are they? And more importantly, how are these sequence generated? I'm pretty sure you've left out some very important details, viz. the description of the process at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first 2x2 matrix tells that you switch symbols (from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0) with probability $q$.

The second 5x5 matrix provides a path towards state 0011. Let us analyze it more carefully:

1. from state "1", you switch to "0" with probability $q$
2. from state "0", you switch to state "00" with probability $p$
3. from state "00", you switch to state "001" with probability $q$
4. from state "001", you switch to state "0011" with probability $p$
5. once in state "0011" you remain there forever

To obtain the 5x5 matrix algorithmically from the 2x2 matrix, note that:

1. first block: the two way principal minor in the upper left corner of the 5x5 matrix matrix equals the 2x2 matrix, except for one entry which is replaced from $p$ to 0.  This entry is now used to represent a transition to the second block
2. second block: the next two way principal minor of the 5x5 matrix matrix again equals the 2x2 matrix, except for two entries which are now replaced from $q$ and $p$ to 0 and 0.  These entries are now used to represent a transition back to the first block or to the last block
3. last block: the last entry of the 5x5 matrix is a self-transition

In summary: the 5x5 matrix contains 3 blocks -- the first block captures the transitions to generate "00", the second block captures the transitions to generate "11" and the last block is a self transition.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this really helped!